# How to count number of strings in a string aggregation in postgresql

Tags: sql, string, postgresql

So I have a table that I'm grouping up by using other columns such as postcodes and I want to aggregate some of the strings and know which type of them, pretty easy to do with the string aggregation function "string_agg(distinct column, ', ' order by column)

Problem is that by doing this I don't know how many strings of each type are being aggregated

So if my table looks like:

```
column A 

Banana 

Monkey

Banana

Thailand

Banana

Monkey
```

My current aggregation returns a field with [Banana, Monkey, Thailand]

When in reality I'd like my output on the same field to be [3 Banana, 2 Monkey, 1 Thailand]

my current non working aggregation query looks something like

```
create table test as select count(a.*), STRING_AGG(cnt::text || ' ' || col, ', ' order by col), a.postcode, a.geom 
FROM tablewithdata a, 
(select col, COUNT(*) AS cnt, postcode, geom FROM tablewithdata 
GROUP BY col, postcode, geom) x 
group by a.postcode, a.geom
```

Is this output possible to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to first make a pass over your table and generate the counts, then aggregate everything together:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT col, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY col
)

SELECT STRING_AGG(cnt::text || ' ' || col, ', ' order by col)
FROM cte;

3 Banana, 2 Monkey, 1 Thailand
```

### Demo

Comment: So I'm trying to implement your query in a subquery in the from but it's really taking a long time. Code looks something like create table test as select count(a.*), STRING_AGG(cnt::text || ' ' || col, ', ' order by col), a.postcode, a.geom FROM tablewithdata a, (select col, COUNT(*) AS cnt, postcode, geom
    FROM tablewithdata
    GROUP BY col, postcode, geom) x
group by a.postcode, a.geom

is there a better way of typing this?

Comment: @Luffydude Honestly, you might want to open a new question.  What you are trying to do looks pretty different from what you asked above.

Comment: I want to have the counts of each aggregated string, I have no use for them if they don't relate to my grouping, otherwise I would just have a count column instead and wouldn't need string aggregation in the first place